# prevent url from xss attack in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, security, xss

I am working on data security web application. I am trying to pass parameters from onw jsp page to another, and it is vulnerable to XSS attack. How can i prevent the attack in jsp

**I tried following things:**

1) My url is : "**localhost:8080/samplejsp.jsp?employeeId=16**", if i try to pass the url like '**localhost:8080/samplejsp.jsp?employeeId=alert(%27Hello%27)**' the alert('Hello') is displayed.

2) I have a button, when i click that button i am opening a new jsp page passing the employeeId to new JSP 
"**localhost:7070/samplejsp1.jsp?employeeId=16**"

3) I tried to restrict the employeeId but validating the regular expression that given input should only be number otherwise i am not redirecting.

4)Now, when i try to click the button passing **"employeeId=alert(%27Hello%27)"** it is still showing the alert message ('Hello') but it is not redirecting to new jsp page

**My question is how to stop the alert message, if XSS(Cross site sciprting) attack occurs? Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on you saying this:

> 3) I tried to restrict the employeeId but validating the regular expression that given input should only be number otherwise i am not redirecting.

Since you are dealing with a number specifically, you can use a real number parsing technique rather than error-ridden regular expressions.

Here's a better way to do that.

```
int number = -1; //initializing with invalid numerical value for your application
try
{
   number = Integer.parseInt(userInputString);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // could not convert the number
   response.sendRedirect("./error.jsp");
   return;
}
```

Or if its too late to do a redirect because you already wrote stuff to the response:

```
if(number == -1) // whatever is an invalid numerical value for your application
{
    out.print("There was an error with the number");
    return;
}
```

If the number needs to be a double then `Double.parseDouble(str)` or float `Float.parseFloat(str)`.

For integers, string values like "1d" will throw an error in parsing.  But for double and float, numbers followed by a "d" or "f" like "1d" and "1f", will go through (i.e. become 1.0 in the numeric variable).  So make sure to use the number variable and not the user input string after parsing the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use owasp-java-encoder https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder

You can use

> Encode.forHtml(userData)

for every user input that is being printed back to page.